# Is there any session token from Okta SAML IDP service that can be reused to login from different app

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, okta

In our case, we have two completely different web apps running on two different domains and platform say app X (which also acts as SAML Service Provider) and app Y. In app X’s login page, the user can choose Okta as SAML SSO service provider, which inturn will redirect him to Okta for credential authentication. Then app X will recieve the SAML Response to verify the assertion and let the user login in to app X.

Now in app X, the the already logged in user can click another link to app Y. The click triggers an HTTP GET request to app Y along with a HTTP Parameter that contains a token (the token was supposed to be recieved from Okta along with either the SAML Assertion recieved by app X OR app X can make any request to Okta to get a special token after it recieving SAML Assertion through some other API exposed by Okta). Now the app Y should use that token to verify with Okta via some custom Okta API service or any other mechanism provided by SAML (that I am not positive).

Is this doable?, if so, someone please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you wan to do here is "federate" two different services via Okta. App X and App Y.

You want to be able to log in to App X via Okta, then from App X, click a link to App Y and be logged in automatically.

If I understood your question correctly, the answer here is that you *can* do this with Okta. But not in the way that you think.

The easiest way to do this would be to SAML enable both App X and App Y, then use the Okta "embed link" for App Y as a link in App X (possibly using the RelayState parameter to tell App X where the user wants to land)

However, this answer gets more complicated depending on how App Y is implemented. If that App isn't easily SAML enabled, then you'll want to look into use OpenID Connect to add Single Sign On capabilities to that application, then use a method similar to what I describe above to link between the apps.

In closing, this is possible, but the recommended method to use here is to have both App X and App Y connected to Okta and use Okta to "federate" the applications for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with the solution of enabling SAML to app Y.